# Error al borrar columnas en VBA para Macros en excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Primero destacar que es la primera vez que intento programar en VBA, dicho esto, mi problema es que intento borrar dos columnas que están vacías pero al especificar cuales son, termina por borrar una pero la siguiente no, de hecho borra otra que no la declare. paso código e imagen para mayor visualización del problema.

Lo que deseo eliminar son las columnas "I" y "K", las pinte para resaltar mas el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego ejecuto este código

```
Sub eliminar()
Columns("I").Delete
Columns("k").Delete
End Sub
```

Este es el resultado obtenido
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien he probado cambiar los nombres de las columnas por su numero

```
Sub eliminar()
Columns(9).Delete
Columns(11).Delete
End Sub
```

siendo el resultado, el mismo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al eliminar una columna, se reacomodan (obviamente las posiciones), por lo que si haces: (a) Borrar Columna 1, (b) Borrar columna 2, en realidad la columna 2, ya no es la columna 2 original sino la 3 que pasó a ser la 2, esto por que son dos operaciones independientes. Para que esto no ocurra, la eliminación debería hacerse sobre un conjunto previamente construido con la selección de las columnas, típicamente, usando [`Range()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) para seleccionar, y sobre esta selección luego aplicamos el `Delete`

```
Range("I:I,K:K").Delete
```

[`Range()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) aplica por defecto a la `ActiveSheet`.